# Combine date and time in string format to a combined datetime object in ionic(angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework

I have a date and time in a string in an ionic project as follows and I want to combine both to have a combined datetime object so I can send it to the server

```
const date = "Fri Jan 07 2022 13:15:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
const time = "2:15 PM";
```

Expected combined result

```
dateTime = 2022-01-07 14:15:00 +0530
```

I tried this code below but it did not work for me. I am getting an error

> 'TypeError: date.replace is not a function'

```
const t1: any = time.split(' ');
const t2: any = t1[0].split(':');
t2[0] = t1[1] === 'PM' ? 1 * t2[0] + 12 : t2[0];
const time24 = (t2[0] < 10 ? '0' + t2[0] : t2[0]) + ':' + t2[1];
const completeDate = date.replace('00:00', time24.toString());
```

Can someone please help achieve this output `dateTime = 2022-01-07 14:15:00 +0530` form the above mentioned string inputs

Comment: where your  getting this date string data? is it new Date()??

Comment: @SaEChowdary It could be any date  selected by the user from the picker

Comment: which picker you are using

Comment: @SaEChowdary Mobiscroll

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have the date object in string format. So i recreated a new Date object with that and altered like this.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Dates</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
const d = new Date("Fri Jan 07 2022 13:15:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
const time = "7:48 PM";
var  t1=time.split(' ');
const t2= t1[0].split(':');
t2[0] = t1[1] === 'PM' ? 1 * t2[0] + 12 : t2[0];
d.setHours(t2[0],t2[1],00);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting error when I use this in ionic  for t2[0]
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Can you share a code snippet that would work for angular